Accumulate load time and retain through a power cut?
I have a question around closing a relay after a load been active for a specific elapsed time; and the time is always known even through a total power cut; ideally din rail components would be able to make the solution.
Firstly, I am not an electrical engineer and only have rudimentary electrical knowhow, so you can consider this a DIY project. I am able to program though, but I don’t think programming is going to help much here, since the environmental factors are not conducive to things like an Arduino or similar because the solution will be installed in an outdoor enclosure.
The background:
A hydrocyclone sand separator absorbs around 17m³ of water twice a week. Due to the centrifugal forces needed to effectively fling the sand out of the water and the pressure the pump produces, the hydrocyclone isn’t big and the water contains a fair percentage of sand. The sand tank at the bottom of the collector needs to be emptied when it is no more than 1/3 full, otherwise it will cease to be effective at collecting the sand. When that happens, the micro filter unit after the hydrocyclone will quickly become clogged and that prevents water discharging from the pump. The pump requires a discharge rate of 8L per minute to prevent destruction. [The pump is costly] This post is about the components needed to automate opening the drain valve at the bottom of the hydrocyclone to ensure that the pump is able to operate within parameters.
Supply = Single Phase 230 V
Irrigation Valve = 24 V –> to open the drain at the bottom of the hydrocyclone.
Assume the 24 V current to the irrigation valve needs to be applied every 15 mins for 10 seconds duration – but these parameters should be adjustable for tuning purposes.
Scope of problem:
I need to be able to accumulate in time [through power cuts, which are common here] how long the pump has run, so that I “know” how much sand is in the collector. Once [for instance] 15 mins runtime has accumulated, I need to close a relay for 10 seconds and then reset the pump runtime to zero. Start to add it up again, close the relay after 15 mins and so on. Clearly, when there is a power cut, the pump won’t run so. . . no more sand will be deposited, but I still need to know where I am in the collection cycle, so I can open the valve before the accumulator is filled. If that is too hard, it would also be acceptable to “drain on power on” and then drain every 15 mins.
Questions:
I am wondering if there is a way to do this with off the shelf components, or if a programmable solution is the only way?
If a programmable solution is the only way, are there components which will stand being outside for 15 years, as the current installation has done, faultlessly ?
I am also assuming that I will essentially power a 230 V ⇾ 24 V transformer when the specified elapsed time has been reached.
Thanks in advance for any help.

You could solve this as a programming exercise, if that’s easiest for you.  If you have an Arduino (for example) that stores its runtime in non-volatile memory then it will keep track of runtime over power cycles.  In a trivial case you might count up seconds and write a value to flash memory every second; when this reaches the desired value you can open the valve, again for a set number of seconds before restarting the cycle from zero.  In practice it’s not ideal to be rewriting flash memory frequently, 100k cycles is typical so one write per second would give a life of about a day.  So you’d want to be a bit smarter, such as updating the runtime every 10 seconds, and writing sequentially to (say) each byte of 1k flash, so you’d get a life of a few years.
As far as the 24V supply is concerned I’d suggest getting an off-the-shelf AC to 24V supply, leave it permanently powered so you don’t need to mess with any high-voltage stuff and then get the Arduino to switch 24V power using a solid state relay.
Is that enough to get started?

Thank you for the guidance that makes allot of sense. I am wondering whether you have  any idea whether the Arduino units are rugged enough to stand up to +40 and -10 Celsius fluctuations and high humidity over the year and whether that would shorten the life of the board? And also whether they can be DIN rail mounted, which is all I have available?

The temperature range shouldn’t be a problem.  Humidity might be an issue but enclosing in a ‘nearly’ waterproof box will tend to trap moisture rather than keep it out.  Conformal coating is a good option - assemble everything and then spray a couple of coats of polyurethane.  DIN rail mounts for Arduino are available from a number of sources.
